# calculate the sum of a column based on another column values(SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

The data is as shown below(Source description and total shares) are the two columns

> Source                494,482,729,319.98998
>      Initial
>      Filtered
>      Final                 494,482,729,319.98998

My expression throws an #Error in output of the report(preview section)

```
=SUM( Fields!total_shares.Value * 
SWITCH(Fields!Source_Description.Value = "Initial" OR Fields!Source_Description.Value = "Inserted", 1,
        Fields!Source_Description.Value = "Filtered" OR Fields!Source_Description.Value = "Deleted" OR Fields!Source_Description.Value = "Final", -1,
        True,0
        )
)
```

Can you please help me where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's unclear how your source data is formatted. Are all those comma separated values in the second column? The `#Error` could be a number of issues. Try breaking the expression into separate ones and see which parts are working. Override the data types with `CDec()`. It might think you're trying to multiply by a string. Also, if you run this report in Visual Studio, it will tell you the exact error message.

Comment: yes comma separated values are in second column. when i give =SUM( Fields!total_shares.Value
    ) it gives me correct value 988,965,458,639.97990 but throws an error when i give the above mentioned expression. it works if the value of each share is less.It only throws error when the value is big.

Comment: cDec() worked. thank you.

Comment: Oh, that's one big number, haha.